# Simple XSD Schema

Tags: xsd

I have problem with my XSD schema. Task is simple, a have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pisemnost nazevSW="EPO MF ČR" verzeSW="40.23.1">
<DPPDP8 verzePis="04.01">

<VetaP>
<VetaO>
<VetaU>   All these elements can be repeated and have any order. 
<VetaE>   They can have any attributes, but they have no content. 
<VetaF>   
<VetaS>  
<VetaUA> 
<VetaUB>
<VetaUD>

<Prilohy>
    -- Any content ---
</Prilohy>
</DPPDP8>
    -- Any content ---
</Pisemnost>
```

I make this XSD schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Pisemnost">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1">

                <xs:element name="DPPDP8">

                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:choice>

                                <xs:element name="VetaD" />
                                <xs:element name="VetaE" />
                                <xs:element name="VetaF" />
                                <xs:element name="VetaO" />
                                <xs:element name="VetaP" />
                                <xs:element name="VetaS" />
                                <xs:element name="VetaU" />
                                <xs:element name="VetaUA" />
                                <xs:element name="VetaUB" />
                                <xs:element name="VetaUD" />

                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="verzePis" />
                    </xs:complexType>

                </xs:element>
                <xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>

            <xs:attribute name="nazevSW" />
            <xs:attribute name="verzeSW" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I would like to add "Prilohy" element with any content to XSD, but all my ideas ends with an invalid XSD. Please, can anybody help me? I ask for help, because I cant XSD and it is complicated for me. Thanks for any ideas :)

Comment: Are you still stuck on this? If so, please edit the question with your latest findings (if any) and I'll provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference DPPDP8 schema from [here](https://adisepo.mfcr.cz/adis/jepo/schema/dppdp8_epo2.xsd) It should look like this:

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Prilohy">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ObecnaPriloha">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:base64Binary">
<xs:attribute name="cislo" use="required">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Pořadové číslo přílohy</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
<xs:totalDigits value="4"/>
<xs:fractionDigits value="0"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="nazev" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Popis přiloženého souboru</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:minLength value="0"/>
<xs:maxLength value="255"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="jm_souboru" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
<strong>Název přiloženého souboru.</strong><br/>povolené typy souborů jsou: DOC, DOCX, RTF, XLS, XLSX, PDF, JPG, TXT a TXT/CSV. Dále je možné přiložit podepsané (formát PKCS#7) a komprimované (formát ZIP) soubory, vždy však jde o jeden podepsaný nebo jeden komprimovaný soubor některého z podporovaných formátů. Součet velikostí všech souborů přiložených v elektronické podobě (tzv. e-příloh) může být nejvýše 4 000 kilobajtů.
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:minLength value="0"/>
<xs:maxLength value="255"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="kodovani" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Kódování přiloženého souboru</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="base64"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PredepsanaPriloha">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:base64Binary">
<xs:attribute name="cislo" use="required">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Pořadové číslo přílohy</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
<xs:totalDigits value="4"/>
<xs:fractionDigits value="0"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="nazev" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Popis přiloženého souboru</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:minLength value="0"/>
<xs:maxLength value="255"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="jm_souboru" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
<strong>Název přiloženého souboru.</strong><br/>povolené typy souborů jsou: DOC, DOCX, RTF, XLS, XLSX, PDF, JPG, TXT a TXT/CSV. Dále je možné přiložit podepsané (formát PKCS#7) a komprimované (formát ZIP) soubory, vždy však jde o jeden podepsaný nebo jeden komprimovaný soubor některého z podporovaných formátů. Součet velikostí všech souborů přiložených v elektronické podobě (tzv. e-příloh) může být nejvýše 4 000 kilobajtů.
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:minLength value="0"/>
<xs:maxLength value="255"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="kodovani" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Kódování přiloženého souboru</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="base64"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="kod" use="required">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Kód přiloženého souboru</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="(PP_OPISPUV){1}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```